# Issues coming after IOS 8 update

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios8

There is a flickering of screen appears when we open the app after splash screen.
And it shows the home screen for a second and then the login screen appears.

It was not happening before IOS 8.

Any idea why it would be happening.

Another thing the API response has also got slow if we install the App on IOS 8 phones or iPads.

AsihttpAsynchronous and Soap is integrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue is solved.

I just added required sized for Splash screen for iPhone 6 and on and the problem solved.

For the other issue When I replaced the ***ASIhttpLibrary with AFNetworking.*** The Api has started working properly.